# Android implementing call back in nested fragments from OnClickListener

Tags: android, android-fragments, callback, android-alertdialog

I'm working on an app that utilizes ActionBar tab navigation that swaps out fragments.  Each tab calls the same listfragment but with a different data set.  When the user selects an item in my list fragment, a detail list fragment is displayed.  Within my detail list fragment, I have a button that displays a dialog containing cross references in an external OnClickListener.

I'm trying to implement a callback in my root list fragment that will display a new detail fragment using data from the dialog selection.

My problem is that I have only one MainActivity and then everything else is fragments.  I'm not sure as how to initiate the call back.

Here is how I initiate my OnClickListener and set it to my button in the OnActivityCreate method of my detail fragment:

```
    // create instance of the OnClickListener
    SeeAlsoOnClickListener seeAlsoListener = new SeeAlsoOnClickListener(this.getActivity(), seeAlsoList, categories);
    button.setOnClickListener(seeAlsoListener);
```

Here is my SeeAlsoOnClickListener class:

```
public class SeeAlsoOnClickListener implements OnClickListener {

private Context context;
private ArrayList<String> categories;
private String[] seeAlsoList;
private String selection;


public SeeAlsoOnClickListener(Context context, String[] array, ArrayList<String> categories) {
    this.context = context;
    this.seeAlsoList = array;
    this.categories = categories;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.see_also_picker, seeAlsoList) {

        ViewHolder holder;
        Drawable icon;

        class ViewHolder {
            ImageView icon;
            TextView title;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(
                            Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(
                        R.layout.see_also_picker, null);

                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.icon = (ImageView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.icon);
                holder.title = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.title);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                // view already defined, retrieve view holder
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }       

            int tile = 0;
            switch (Integer.parseInt(categories.get(position))) {
                case 0:
                    tile = context.getResources().getIdentifier("acronyms","drawable",context.getPackageName());
                    break;
                case 1:
                    tile = context.getResources().getIdentifier("algorithm","drawable",context.getPackageName());
                    break;
                case 2:
                    tile = context.getResources().getIdentifier("anatomy","drawable",context.getPackageName());
                    break;
                case 3:
                    tile = context.getResources().getIdentifier("calculator","drawable",context.getPackageName());
                    break;
                case 4:
                    tile = context.getResources().getIdentifier("medicine","drawable",context.getPackageName());
                    break;
                case 5:
                    tile = context.getResources().getIdentifier("treatment","drawable",context.getPackageName());
                    break;
            }

            holder.title.setText(seeAlsoList[position]);
            holder.icon.setImageResource(tile);

            return convertView;
        }
    };

    // display alert dialog
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setTitle("See Also");
    builder.setAdapter(adapter,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int item) {                      
                    // get the selection
                    selection = seeAlsoList[item];                  
                }
            });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
}
```

This all works well except I need to swap out to another fragment based on the selection.  Any thoughts or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks in Advanced.

Comment: Not sure I understand. Is this what you need?http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest two ways for you:

1)You can define callback interface in non list fragment, implement this callback in MainActivity and get callback instance in onAttach() method of fragment. Than in activity, with findFragmentById() or findFragmentByTag() you can obtain direct link to your ListFragment and call public method, you defined theme, swapData(datalist), for example.

More detail on this approach - [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html).

2) Define BroadcastReceiver in list fragment and swap data in onReceive() method, based on Extra data. From onClick() method of dialog you should send broadcast with needed data in Extras.